# C# Typecast an Enum to a Struct

Tags: c#, struct, enums

I'm using C#, and I have to manipulate an object on the screen. I setup a struct to hold the coordinates, and then I setup an enum to restrict the number of directions that could be moved.

```
private enum Direction
{
    UpperLeft = new Coord(-1, -1), 
    UpperCenter = new Coord(0, -1), 
    UpperRight = new Coord(1, -1),
    Left = new Coord(-1, 0), 
    Right = new Coord(1, 0),
    LowerLeft = new Coord(-1, 1), 
    LowerCenter = new Coord(0, 1),
    LowerRight = new Coord(1, 1)
};

private struct Coord
{
    public int row { get; private set; }
    public int col { get; private set; }
    public Coord(int r, int c) : this()
    {
        row = r;
        col = c;
    }

    public static Coord operator +(Coord a, Coord b)
    {
        return new Coord(a.row + b.row, a.col + b.col);
    }
}
```

Basically what I am aiming to do is to have the object I have on the screen move based on the assigned enum.

So I'd like to hypothetically use it like this or something:

```
public class ThingThatMovesToTheLeft
{
    Direction dir = Direction.Left;
    Coord pos = new Coord(0,0);
    public void Move()
    {
        this.pos = this.dir + this.pos;
    }
}
```

**Essentially my question** is how do I typecast my enum back to my struct so I can use it in this manner? I can't seem to be able to cast it back to the struct. (Additionally, VisualStudio let me assign the enum to those Coord structs without complaining so I assumed that it was okay to assign an struct to an enum, is this acceptable practice or should this just not be done?)

Comment: You should make the `Direction`s static properties in the Coord class and ditch the `Direction` enum.

Comment: Your `enum` declaration does not work like that. You can only assign integer numbers to enum constants, not whole structs or anything else. That is why trying to compile the enum results in the CS0029 error message (*Cannot implicitly convert type 'Coord' to 'int'*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want complex objects to be statically available, you'll need to use public static variables, like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public static class People
{
    public static Person Jack= new Person("Jack", "Andersson");
}
```

This is because Enums are special constructs that have special behavior in switch case constructs, or with the pipe operator.

Edit: I was wrong, enums are just syntax sugar for primitive types.

I'm no expert, so I'm not saying I'm 100% sure there isn't another way, but I would make your directions class like this:

```
private static class Directions
{
    private static readonly Coord UpperLeft = new Coord(-1, -1);
    private static readonly Coord UpperCenter = new Coord(0, -1);
    private static readonly Coord UpperRight = new Coord(1, -1),
    private static readonly Coord Left = new Coord(-1, 0); 
    private static readonly Coord Right = new Coord(1, 0);
    private static readonly Coord LowerLeft = new Coord(-1, 1);
    private static readonly Coord LowerCenter = new Coord(0, 1);
    private static readonly Coord LowerRight = new Coord(1, 1);
};
```

Comment: Actually, they are not "special constructs" with special behavior anywhere, they are just ordinary integers with the usual integer behavior with respect to `switch`-`case` and the bitwise operators.

Comment: Ah alright. Like I said, not an expert. ;-) I'll edit my answer

Comment: Best solution, just as side note better make the fields `readonly`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks, I'll go this route instead!

Answer (score 3):

Your `enum` declaration is wrong, as you didn't specify what type you're mapping your enum to:

```
private enum Direction : Coord //good idea, but this won't work ;)
....
```

BUT you can't map enums to structs or classes. Based on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sbbt4032.aspx) documentation

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be **any integral type except char**. The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int. To declare an enum of another integral type, such as byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type, as shown in the following example.

So, if you try the above, then you will see the compiler throwing a fit, because `Coord` is not the expected type.

I think the best solution to your problem would be to define some `const` variables and use those.

Comment: +1 I was about to downvote looking at `private enum Direction : Coord`. I overlooked it. sorry..:)

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple converter ? Let's start with the enum :

```
public enum Direction
{
    UpperLeft = 0, // Coord(-1, -1),
    Left = 1, // Coord(-1, 0),
    LowerLeft = 2, // Coord(-1, 1),
    UpperCenter = 3, // Coord(0, -1),
    LowerCenter = 5, // Coord(0, 1),
    UpperRight = 6, // Coord(1, -1),
    Right = 7, // Coord(1, 0),
    LowerRight = 8, // Coord(1, 1)
}
```

keep your Coord class, and implement a converter :

```
private static Coord ConvertDirectionToCoord(Direction dir)
{
    return new Coord((int)dir / 3 - 1, (int)dir % 3 - 1);
}
```

you can so write your ThingThatMovesToTheLeft class like this :

```
public class ThingThatMovesToTheLeft
{
    Direction dir = Direction.Left;
    Coord pos = new Coord(0, 0);
    public void Move()
    {
        this.pos = ConvertDirectionToCoord(this.dir) + this.pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever answer. I'm going to +1 this even though I'm going to take a different route. I can totally use something like this for something else I'm working on!